# What type of coding has been used in this communication?

Tags: digital-communications

I am trying to decode this signal coming from a control board for car ultrasound sensors.
[image: Segnal read with oscilloscope]
The first part of the signal seems to be a kind of sync frame. In the second part, instead, I should find the sensor id and the detected distance. The third part should be a reset.

I think it's encoded in PWM or Manchester encoding.
Can anybody give me some more information?

**UPDATE N.1:**
Opening the case, i found this board:
[image: Control Board]
It is driven by this microcontroller: UPD78F9222MC(T)-5A4-A - Microcontrollore 8 Bit, 78K0S/Kx, 10 MHz, 4 KB, 256 Byte, 20 Pin, SSOP.
So trasmission should be UART or LIN (but i think that is UART).

I expect as payload some bits (min. 3) that can identify one of eight's sensor, and a float that rappresent distance.

Comment: Well, *you* could give more information. For example, how many bits of payload do you expect?

Comment: Don't you have the sensor's datasheet? It will tell you what type of communication protocol is implemented and therefore expected from the MCU that communicates with the sensor.

Comment: I made an update